# MySQL Lock A Table

Tags: mysql, locking

How do you lock a table in MySQL so that you cannot edit or drop it no matter what unless you unlock it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Locking" a table generally means restricting access to the data in the table by other processes while the data is being edited. To secure a table so that it can't be altered or dropped, I think the best solution would be to change the permissions of the table, removing DROP, UPDATE, INSERT and whatever other permissions you want to restrict, for that specific table.

```
REVOKE DROP, INSERT, TRUNCATE ON database.table FOR 'user'@'host';
```

Comment: I think this may be what the asker is looking for.  For instance, a lock only lasts as long as your connection. So if you disconnect, even accidental, like your network connection stopped working, the table can then be dropped.  Locks are for temporarily blocking access to a table and defintely don't fulfill the requirement of "cannot edit or drop it no matter what"

Comment: yes that is perfect. i was wondering why locking did not work permanently. thanks!

Comment: You may not be able to revoke TRUNCATE, actually. Replace it with DELETE and UPDATE, and any other privileges you want removed. You can use SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'host'; to get a list of permissions that need to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`LOCK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) keyword for that.

```
LOCK TABLES t1 READ;
```

Here is the syntax:

```
LOCK TABLES
    tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type
    [, tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type] ...
```

Where:

```
lock_type:
    READ [LOCAL]
  | [LOW_PRIORITY] WRITE
```

Read the docs for more info and the requirements needed to lock a table for example this also depends on your db engine type.